# Double port forwarding - SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding, ssh-agent

**NOTE:** *I'm not explaining why I want to do this. But here is the requirement.*

**There are 4 hosts. Host A, Host B, Host C, Host D**

1. Host A is running some application which can be accessed at port 8001
2. I forwarded port 8001 of Host A to 8002 of Host B.
3. Host B is accessible only using Host C.

So, again, I forwarded port 8002 of Host B to 8003 of Host C.

Now, from Host D...when I say: `https://HostC:8003` -- it should take me to the application running on Host A. But I'm not able to do that.

But what I could do was, I forwarded port 22 of Host A to port 7777 of Host B. Then, from Host C, I ran:

```
$ ssh Host B -p 7777 -L 6666:localhost:8001
```

Doing this, `ssh Host B -p 7777`, took me to a command line on Host A. Hence port 8001 of Host A was directly forwarded to 6666 of Host C.

Now, from Host D, `https://Host C:8001` worked! But, I want to do it using the former way.

- How can I do that?
- What am I missing here?

Comment: "I forwarded port 8001 of Host A to 8002 of Host B." You probably mean that the other way round. (And "I forwarded port 8002 of Host B to 8003 of Host C", too.)

Comment: you work the other way around, forward port xxx of Host C to port yyy of host B  forward port yyy of host B to host A on port sss then you will be able to connect from d to a

Comment: You have not explained how you do the port forward. I guess you rewrite the target address without adapting the source address so that A answers directly to D which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide the exact commands you're using. By default, the ssh arguments `-L` and `-R` listen on `localhost` only. We can't tell if this is the case without seeing what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do it the other way round (reverse of your set-up).

```
Host D -> Host C:8003
          forwards to --> Host B:8002
                           forwards to --> Host A:8001 -> Your application
```

You only have 1 ssh forward to establish.

On hostC

```
ssh -L 8003:hostA:8001 user@hostB
```

then to test on hostD by accessing hostC:8003

Comment: Is there a simple iptable rule that i can run for destination nat from Host C -- so that whenever request comes to port 8003 of Host C, it will get redirected to 8002 of Host B. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not an iptable expert sorry, maybe that's a new question. First make sure it works as you want with ssh.

Comment: and what if it says 'network unavaliable'

Comment: @Serge You don't say which network is unavailable, I would login into to each host (starting on the right) and check where the error occurs. Possibly a firewall restriction.